# return variable from PHP class to another class

Tags: php, class

```
class department {
    function get($department,$info) {
        //do something
    }
}

class employment {
    function get($user_id,$info) {
        //do something
    }
}

$dept = new department();
$emp = new employment();

$dept->get($emp->get($_SESSION['i'],'dept'), "open");
```

I am trying to get the output variable from the `$emp->get()` function and put it into the `$dept->get()` function, but the output from `$emp->get()` is not processed by 
 `$dept->get()`.

How should I pass the value returned from `$emp->get()` to `$dept->get()`?

Comment: try `var_dump($emp->get($_SESSION['i'],'dept'))` and check if it returns something..

Comment: Yes it returns something from the code including bool(true). Even echo works on the $emp->get() function, but once inside the $dept->get() function, it wont return the value

Comment: @ptewee can you show what is the result of `var_dump($emp->get($_SESSION['i'],'dept'))`.

Comment: it returns: `MANbool(true)`, `MAN` is the value i want to pass to the `$dept->get();` function

Comment: `echo $emp->get($_SESSION['i'],'dept');` gives me `MAN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the output from `$emp->get()` is an `echo`, not a `return`, so it wasn't accepted by `$dept->get()`. My mistake!

Answer (score 2):

classes are not initialised like this

```
$dept = new $department();
$emp = new $employment();
```

the proper syntax is

```
$dept = new department;
$emp = new employment;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: Thanks, I hand wrote the question without copying direct from my code, so those were my mistakes. I've edited my question